# Cache-control in response headers

Tags: http-headers

I have this server response for a file that I want not to be cached from the browsers. The response has two cache control headers.

- Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate (which is what I want and)
- Cache-Control: private (which is appended by default from netscaler and the server side guys tell me they cannot remove it)

My question is which one will prevail?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 20 Jan 2014 15:29:53 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Fri, 17 Jan 2014 16:50:54 GMT
ETag: "682-4f02d58643780"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cteonnt-Length: 1666
P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTR STP IND DEM"
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=1000
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/javascript
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: private
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 716
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2), setting the same header multiple times should be equivalent to setting it once with all values separated by comas.

> Multiple message-header fields with the same field-name MAY be present in a message if and only if the entire field-value for that header field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)]. It MUST be possible to combine the multiple header fields into one "field-name: field-value" pair, without changing the semantics of the message, by appending each subsequent field-value to the first, each separated by a comma.

So in your case, it would be equivalent to

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, private
```

`private` will just further prevent the response to be cached by a proxy between the server and the browser, so it shouldn't have any adverse effect.

Answer (score 0):

Having researched a similar issue for a client, I can tell you from my own experience that, if this content is being served through a Citrix NetScaler and compression has been enabled, anything with a content-type of text will have a Cache-Control: private value set by the NetScaler. How you're getting two entries is beyond me. However, Yolanda's answer is most likely correct. The only reason for the caveat is that RFC2616 was superseded in 2014. (See https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html)

Regarding the NetScaler adding/replacing the Cache-Control header, it appears that it can be turned off; You just have to know how. Had to open a case with Citrix to learn about CTX124717 (FAQ:Preventing the Cache-Control Response Header from being Set to private).

If compression is enabled on the NetScaler, two of the default policies (ns_cmp_content_type and ns_adv_cmp_content_type) "compress data when the response contains Content-Type header and contains text" (see http://docs.citrix.com/en-us/netscaler/10-5/ns-optimization-wrapper-10-con/ns-compression-gen-wrapper-con/ns-compression-configactions-tsk.html). Using the NetScaler API Mgr (nsapimgr) you can prevent the Compression feature from adding the Cache-Control response header (nsapimgr -ys cmp_no_cc_hdr=1).